# java regex search-and-replace module

Tags: java, regex, substitution

Perl has fullblown regexp support for inline search-and-replace substitution.  Anything like that in a Java module?  There was the Jakarta Regexp project but it is on ice.  Same with ORO which had a Perl5Util calling a Perl5Compiler.  Haven't tested, wondering if there is something else....

Comment: "inline"? You mean in the language? As in `blah =~ s/something/else/g;` (or similar) instead of `blah = blah.replaceAll('something', 'else')`? I don't think so - perl  is fairly unique in that (JavaScript partially borrows that syntax and though I'm sure there are other languages that also do it but they're not as common/popular). I'd be awfully surprised if someone figured out a way to do that in the Java language

Comment: exactly, inline substitution like in Perl.

Comment: Welp, then I'm pretty sure the answer is no :( sorry!

Answer (score 0):

There is an Eclipse plugin named [QuickRex](http://sourceforge.net/projects/quickrex/).

Comment: QuickRex apparently has the ability to plugin different implementations like Jakarta Regexp or JRegex and so forth.  Looked quickly at JRegex and it isn't exactly what I am looking for (what what Perl can do, on-the-fly substitution).

Answer (score 0):

As of Java 1.4, regex is built in to the language with the java.util.regex package.  Also, there are convenience methods like `String.matches`.

```
"The quick brown fox".matches("ick") == true
```